# Is it possible to use Bitcoin-core for multisig? Can it handle change addresses?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, multi-signature, hardware-wallet, bip174-psbt

I have tried to import three xpub in a watch-only wallet as keypool with `importmulti` and a multisig output descriptor and to fill the first address with some BTCs. When I try to spend the newly created multisig UTXO, creating a `walletcreatefundedpsbt`, there's an error instead of creating a psbt.
For context, my intention is to protect the wallet with three Hardware wallets. I' m doing this tests in regtest. 
Here are the details:
I have generated three xpub:

```
pubkey1 tpubD6NzVbkrYhZ4YKMs9TvzemC7FaKYnNxESKvYN9V6PDnDwBXrHQk97rNC71fCXxyobFgcZDfesc5ThCMkUYjA5edd8J1qUQoR4P3kPywrGw6
pubkey2 tpubD6NzVbkrYhZ4X2MQYSo3wVWBPGjV3fUcN4DywfR2ZcM1F56A2bapN54YJqa47yDvwuTajWqkBHxRmdGHLQJj5ae7V1NXDN2JP8AKcyurzsa
pubkey3 tpubD6NzVbkrYhZ4XYeFSXzJ9fFu91eiSEpanzbhifxuSAb7m4piv9QxXsHi2a9jnspQpeKpnpdsyNhoMWb6traBXErL9TPjP3EKnPVFuzyv7Ed
```

then I have created a disable_private_keys wallet.

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest createwallet multi
```

then imported the output descriptors in the new wallet.

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=multi importmulti [{"desc": "wsh(multi(2,tpubD6NzVbkrYhZ4YKMs9TvzemC7FaKYnNxESKvYN9V6PDnDwBXrHQk97rNC71fCXxyobFgcZDfesc5ThCMkUYjA5edd8J1qUQoR4P3kPywrGw6/1/*,tpubD6NzVbkrYhZ4X2MQYSo3wVWBPGjV3fUcN4DywfR2ZcM1F56A2bapN54YJqa47yDvwuTajWqkBHxRmdGHLQJj5ae7V1NXDN2JP8AKcyurzsa/1/*,tpubD6NzVbkrYhZ4XYeFSXzJ9fFu91eiSEpanzbhifxuSAb7m4piv9QxXsHi2a9jnspQpeKpnpdsyNhoMWb6traBXErL9TPjP3EKnPVFuzyv7Ed/0/*))#hnd2wec3", "internal": true, "range": [0, 10], "timestamp": "now", "keypool": true, "watchonly": true},{"desc": "wsh(multi(2,tpubD6NzVbkrYhZ4YKMs9TvzemC7FaKYnNxESKvYN9V6PDnDwBXrHQk97rNC71fCXxyobFgcZDfesc5ThCMkUYjA5edd8J1qUQoR4P3kPywrGw6/0/*,tpubD6NzVbkrYhZ4X2MQYSo3wVWBPGjV3fUcN4DywfR2ZcM1F56A2bapN54YJqa47yDvwuTajWqkBHxRmdGHLQJj5ae7V1NXDN2JP8AKcyurzsa/0/*,tpubD6NzVbkrYhZ4XYeFSXzJ9fFu91eiSEpanzbhifxuSAb7m4piv9QxXsHi2a9jnspQpeKpnpdsyNhoMWb6traBXErL9TPjP3EKnPVFuzyv7Ed/0/*))#6jvyd6m3", "internal": false, "range": [0, 10], "timestamp": "now", "keypool": true, "watchonly": true}]
```

I have filled the first multisig address:

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet="" sendtoaddress $(bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=multi getaddressesbylabel ""|jq -r 'keys|.[0]') 10
bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet="" generatetoaddress 1 $(bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet="" getnewaddress)
```

but then, when I do:

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=multi walletcreatefundedpsbt [] "{\"$(bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet="" getnewaddress)\":0.5}" 0 "{\"subtractFeeFromOutputs\":[0], \"includeWatching\":true}"
```

I get:

```
    error code: -4
error message:
Can't generate a change-address key. No keys in the internal keypool and can't generate any keys.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a way to manage the internal keypool so to have a multisig whatch-only wallet I can use with two or three HWW?

Thank you.